# Map pandas dataframes based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of addresses in DF1 that I am trying to map to DF2. However, there is not always an exact match to map it to. Here's what I have so far:

```
df1
    address    
0   123 Main Rd, Charlotte NC
1   123 ABC Drive Charlotte NC


df2
    HouseNo    StreetName   StreetSuffix   City
0   123        MAIN         Road           Charlotte
1   123        MAIN         Road           Raleigh
2   123        ABC          Drive          Charlotte
3   987        XYZ          Avenue         Greensboro
```

Current Solution:

```
list = df1["address"].values.tolist()
list_upper = [item.upper() for item in list]
print(list_upper)

df2["short_address"] = df2["HouseNo"].astype(str) + " " + df2["StreetName"]

master_df = df2[[any(x in y for y in list_upper) for x in df2["short_address"]]]
```

The current solution would return

```
master_df
    HouseNo    StreetName   StreetSuffix   City
0   123        MAIN         Road           Charlotte
1   123        MAIN         Road           Raleigh
2   123        ABC          Drive          Charlotte
```

However, this is incorrect because it is pulling in 123 MAIN Street in the city of Raleigh and not just Charlotte. I also cannot add city to df2["short_address"] field because the StreetSuffix are different. Sometimes they're abbreviated vs fully spelled out.

Expected output:

```
master_df
    HouseNo    StreetName   StreetSuffix   City
0   123        MAIN         Road           Charlotte
1   123        ABC          Drive          Charlotte
```

Is there a way to modify the following code but also add that it includes the city or another criteria? Something like if any df2["short address"] AND df2["city"] is in a record of df1, then match?

```
master_df = df2[[any(x in y for y in list_upper) for x in df2["short_address"]]]
```

However, this is not a good enough match indicator alone.

Comment: Does your `df2` always have a consistent format? i.e. `Road ` is always Road and not `Rd` ?

Comment: I'll second what @JuanC asked, and add that this is probably pushing the limits of what Pandas alone can realistically do.

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: You should be able to, but you'll need some regex and specify/group all your cases

Comment: I agree with @Juan C. There may be parsing packages that can save you some time vs. writing regular expressions, for example https://github.com/datamade/usaddress.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I can come up with is using parsing package usaddress as @ralex mentioned. Some limitations, but mostly it works.

I run each address in df1 through the parsing package and it breaks out the individual components. I can then re-consolidate these in any form of a unique identifier to match the format of df2. That allows me to then map them cleanly.

```
import usaddress

df2["short_address"] = df2["HouseNo"].astype(str) + " " + df2["StreetName"] + " " + df2["cityName"]

def f(x):
    norm_address = usaddress.tag(x)
     addressNum = norm_address[0]["AddressNumber"]
    streetName = norm_address[0]["StreetName"]
    placeName = norm_address[0]["PlaceName"]
    zipCode = norm_address[0]["ZipCode"]
    revised = addressNum + " " + streetName + " " + placeName
    return revised

df1["usaddress_norm"] = df["address"].apply(f)

list = df["usaddress_norm"].values.tolist()
list_upper = [item.upper() for item in list]
print(list_upper)

master_df = df2[[any(x in y for y in list_upper) for x in df2["short_address"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) approach and compare all caps using Python string functions (`upper`, `split`) and Pandas functions ([`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html)):

**Data**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = '''address    
0   "123 Main Rd, Charlotte NC"
1   "123 ABC Drive Charlotte NC"'''

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")

txt = '''    HouseNo    StreetName   StreetSuffix   City
0   123        MAIN         Road           Charlotte
1   123        MAIN         Road           Raleigh
2   123        ABC          Drive          Charlotte
3   987        XYZ          Avenue         Greensboro'''

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")
```

**Clean**

```
# RE-BUILD DF1
df1 = (df1['address'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.upper().split()))
           .replace("(,|\\.)", "", regex = True)                     # REMOVE PERIODS/COMMAS
           .replace({'AVE':'AVENUE', 
                     'RD':'ROAD', 
                     'DR':'DRIVE',
                     'BLVD':'BOULEVARD'}, value = None)              # REPLACE ABBREVIATIONS
           .set_axis(["HouseNo", "StreetName", "StreetSuffix",
                      "City", "State"],                              # RENAME COLUMNS
                     axis = 1, inplace = False)
      )    
df1
#   HouseNo StreetName StreetSuffix       City State
# 0     123       MAIN         ROAD  CHARLOTTE    NC
# 1     123        ABC        DRIVE  CHARLOTTE    NC

# DF2 CONVERT ALL COLUMNS TO UPPER CASE STRING
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())
df2
#   HouseNo StreetName StreetSuffix        City
# 0     123       MAIN         ROAD   CHARLOTTE
# 1     123       MAIN         ROAD     RALEIGH
# 2     123        ABC        DRIVE   CHARLOTTE
# 3     987        XYZ       AVENUE  GREENSBORO
```

**Merge**

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2)

df3
#   HouseNo StreetName StreetSuffix       City State
# 0     123       MAIN         ROAD  CHARLOTTE    NC
# 1     123        ABC        DRIVE  CHARLOTTE    NC
```